# Is the Android volley library compatible with all Android versions?

Tags: android, android-volley

It is said that older versions of Android had bugs with certain networking http requests.

Does the Volley library reliably work for all versions of Android - given the fact that there are implementation bugs in some versions of Android?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html, *DEPENDENCIES AND PREREQUISITES

Android 1.6 (API Level 4) or higher*

Comment: @blackbelt, that's the compatible version, but not necessarily what works well?

Answer (score 1):

Volley works with Api level 4 or higher levels

Comment: @DaviddCeFreitas >= 2.0